# Why was this question with upvoted answers deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, dmca-notice

According to this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) the author  can't delete a question if it has an answer with upvotes. *To my understanding* the question was not deleted by the system itself either.

So my question is, why was the following question deleted?

[image]

Comment: It can't be deleted by the *author*, but it can still be deleted by *others*. Can you link the question?

Comment: Either you managed to have a post that netted you 108 rep with a negative score (i.e 14 upvotes and 16 downvotes), or the post was deleted by someone other than the author.

Comment: I've posted a picture with the question's title. I am unable to access the question anymore. Question title is / was `How to find weather a given date range is overlapped in a collection of list using Java8`

Comment: Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52622085

Comment: It was deleted by mod .. Mod comment on question https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGAqo.png

Comment: I am unable to see any copyright infringement in neither the question nor the answer. My proposed solution is based on an implementation from https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844 which to my understanding is public knowledge and not subject to copyright.

Comment: [TestDome](https://www.testdome.com/questions) seems to be a testing platform for job seekers... This is probably more to do with the question than your proposed solution I am guessing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what they claim IP on. If tomorrow TestDome will say they own QuickSort, will all questions related to QuickSort be deleted as well?

Comment: Should I avoid answering any question related to algorithms since TestDome will come and claim DMCA infringement, resulting in a complete waste of time on my side?

Comment: It may be a frivolous DMCA takedown; they kind of dominate the space.  There are provisions in the DMCA for punishments for bad faith assertions, but they are never enforced.  The recourse is for the content poster to push back against the DMCA notice; if you didn't get an email with it, I'm guessing it's the asker.  This question may come from TestDome, and they don't want their tests being public knowledge.

Comment: Their are claiming IP on a particular case of this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling

Comment: So their tests *are* public knowledge. At least this one anyway.

Comment: It's in no way different than me claiming IP on a specific case of QuickSort on entities of type Person based on person age. The thing is, I can't legally enforce that claim.

Comment: Welcome to the hodgepodge that is the DMCA.  *Anyone* can claim they own something, and any content host *has* to take it down, or they risk losing their safe harbor exemption under the DMCA.  So there's literally no downside for people to shotgun them across the web.

Comment: Although the content of the specific question is behind a paywall, it appears that the OP posted the content of [this question](https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/movie-night/21575?visibility=3&skillId=4) from TestDome. So a DMCA takedown makes sense.

Comment: Yes, `movies`, along with `courses` for example, tend to be used when defining an interval scheduling problem since giving the problem in the form presented on Wikipedia tends to be a little too abstract. It's in essence the same question as the one from Wikipedia (From Wikipedia: The interval scheduling maximization problem (ISMP) is to find a largest compatible set - a set of non-overlapping intervals of maximum size. The goal here is to execute as many tasks as possible.).

Comment: Just because you use `movies` when you define the problem doesn't mean you have any IP on it.

Comment: Alex, the issue is not the technology, it's that the OP posted their specific content and was trying to get answers to it. I.e. OP were cheating.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Please look at the grammar in OPs question. I believe we can both agree it's not copy paste from a site specializing in asking coding questions.And regarding the `idea` of watching the maximum numbers of movies, that's not subject to IP.

Comment: They said they are trying to implement the `canViewAll` method. The abstract of the question on TestDome says, *Implement the `canViewAll` method...*

Comment: A follow up question that should be asked of SE is who is notified of this DMCA removal (someone should be - is it the question asker, any one who answered, only the specific post that was DMCA'd, some combination, etc) and what the counter notice process is, because that should also be a thing.

Comment: Yes, `canViewAll` seems like a good candidate for the method name. You can't claim IP on a method name.

Comment: @Andy I did not receive any email

Comment: Alex... slow down. The DMCA was against the **question**, not your **answer**. You have done nothing wrong.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I was quite sure the DMCA had nothing against my answer since *I know* I've written that code myself, along with all the explanatory content from it. What bugs me is that I've lost reputation on something that to me looks like a bogus DMCA claim.

Comment: DMCA is about copyright. TestDome wrote the question that OP included in their question (probably with other stuff around it so it wouldn't be obvious it was copied from a test). We can't see the content of the TestDome question, but most likely a significant chunk of the code in the question is copied from the test. So they are (correctly) claiming copyright over that code.

Comment: Well, both the implementations for `canViewAll` are bad from a performance standpoint and non-compliant with the Java coding standards, so they unlikely come from a site specializing in coding interviews. The grammar is bad as well, so I'll assume that is not copy pasted either. The only thing that could potentially be copy pasted from there is the `Movie` entity, along with a `main` with an array that contains some `Movie` objects.

Comment: You can't really claim IP on a main with a `List` and a `Movie` entity.

Comment: And that is obvious from the fact they did not provide some context over what exactly infringes their copyright.

Comment: @AlexRolea You may want to review your knowledge of copyright and intellectual property law, or maybe not make incorrect legal claims. Code is definitely copyrightable, even if it may look trivial.

Comment: @Andy you might be interested in [My post was removed due to DMCA Takedown Notice — what can I do?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4050) and the recently asked [What is the policy for DMCA takedowns, and what can we expect in terms of transparency regarding the removed content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317709)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In order for the code to be the subject of copyright, it has to " exhibit a minimum of originality". I've written a new post here detailing the issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376183/question-deleted-due-to-dmca-notice . Bottom line, *try* to understand the context before providing an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am very much not a lawyer, but based on a quick Google, it looks to me like there *is* a minimum level of non-triviality at which content becomes copyrightable. If - as seems to be the case based on surface appearances, though it's hard to tell with the original paywalled - the only content copied here was the method name `canViewAll` and the declaration of a `List` of `Movie` objects, I wouldn't be surprised if Alex is right to assert that TestDome doesn't actually have copyright on that content - even *before* we get into the question of whether it was Fair Use under US law.

Comment: @SurajRao wait, the DMCA was served by an elected moderator not by an employee? That isn't good.

Comment: @Braiam ah my bad..it was deleted and the comment was by an employee..

Comment: @MarkAmery And only a court of law can decide if a work is too trivial: we can have an opinion, but ultimately we aren't the one to decide.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The legal statement in discussion is "exhibit a minimum of originality", it has nothing to do with *triviality*.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ignorance is not always bliss. Having the ability to read (and to a certain degree understand) legal statements, so you can have an *informed opinion* (i.e. based on laws) regarding *what is likely* that a court of law will decide **is** valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This post was removed due to a DMCA request from TestDome.

I do not have any further information than that though.

Comment: This answers the question as stated yet leaves two massive questions in its wake.

Comment: I would be really curious to know which is the infringement.

Comment: @AlexRolea:  That's really not for us mortals to know.  DMCA works in devious and subversive ways.  I'd rather pose a question as to how the DMCA process across the network works, since this is easily the second or third time I've seen content that seems innocuous to my non-legal mind just disappear without reason or rationale.  Andy's done his part in telling us what happened to the question, so let's not flood his inbox much further...

Comment: TestDome is a testing site (unsurprisingly) My guess is that the code posted was from one of the questions they ask and don't want that code being easy to find online and allow people to cheat. I guess I can understand their point of view on this.

Comment: @DavidG It seems to be [this question](https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/movie-night/21575?visibility=3&skillId=4).

Comment: OK, but it hasn't really been taken down.  It's still visible to users with 10k+ rep.  Surely a DMCA takedown notice requires that the content NOT be visible; rather than simply restricted to "advanced" users?

Answer (score 22):

Ignoring why or how it was deleted, just reverse engineer a question for which your answer is valid. Read your answer, carefully, and attempt to write a question which that answer applies. Remove irrelevant details, that aren't the core of your answer.

Comment: *"Read your answer, carefully"* - but Alex doesn't have *access* to his answer, because it's deleted and he has <10k rep. (He also has no way of knowing whether it was the content of the question or of his answer that attracted TestDome's DMCA request, and so no way of knowing whether a repost of an equivalent answer would just immediately attract another DMCA request and get nuked again.)

Comment: @MarkAmery "If you don't have the moderator tools privilege, you can see any of your own questions that you have the direct link to, and your own deleted answers to any question. Additionally, you can see any deleted question you have answered as well as your answer(s) to it provided you have the direct link, but you can't see other users' answers to it, neither can you see the question's revision history."

Comment: Huh. Sorry - didn't know that. Good feature!