# Should I be able to see deleted questions I've answered? Or an 'undelete answer' option when I don't have 20k reputation?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, dmca-notice

A couple of days ago, I was greeted on Stack Overflow with an indication that my reputation had just gone down by 25 points. I discovered that it was because a question that I had answered (accepted + one up-vote = 25) had been "removed."

Now, the -25 rep hit is really not that big a deal ... but the event got me thinking: I seem to remember that a user cannot delete their own question if it: (a) has upvotes; or (b) has an answer with upvotes. This question had both.

I eventually tracked down the question (*via* the link to my answer) and noticed that a moderator had deleted it. Now, I'm not here challenging the moderator's action (I think I know why - see later) but what I am curious about is:

1. Is it appropriate that I can see deleted questions (Note: I was < 10K when I posted this question) simply because I gave an answer?
2. I noticed I have an "undelete" option on my answer (but not on the question); what would happen if I clicked that? The hover text says "vote to undelete" - but I don't have that privilege. (I'm not going to 'find out by doing' here, because I don't disagree with the original deletion.)

**Probable/Possible Reason for Closure:**

The question involved participation in an online quiz. The OP had made this very clear, giving their submitted code in the question, and the reason why it failed, asking for clarification on what that reason meant. In a comment to my answer, the OP had even stated that the quiz was now closed. However, at some point shortly after I had answered, somebody had posted a remark (maybe in another question, or possibly in this one) that the quiz was still open (and specified a closing date). So, assuming all this is on-track:

3. Is it possible the moderator will "undelete" the question once the aforementioned closing date has passed?

There are a number of discussions here on Meta about what to do when confronted with such "Quiz" questions; I don't think my answer really broke any of the guidelines. But, like I said, I'm happy with the -25, and perhaps I should have been less hasty in posting my answer.

*Note: I shall refrain from posting a link to the deleted question, as that may break the 'spirit' of the moderator's actions. However, if a moderator says here that it's OK, then I'll include the link (at least, that to my answer).*

Comment: '*Is it possible the moderator will "undelete" the question once the aforementioned closing date has passed?*' - Realistically the mod has forgotten all about this question so no, not unless reminded. Also, I don't think there should be an issue linking the question because only those who have 10k will be able to see it and I see no reason why it would be problematic for them to see it seeing as they have the privilege to do so.

Comment: @Script47 Ha! Probably, so true - but I could be tempted to somehow ping the mod! 

Comment: Regarding your "2.": you can try it, you should only get a popup saying that you can't undelete posts deleted by moderator.

Comment: "As of February 28th, 2017, authors of *answers* to deleted questions can also view them... ([from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179511/165773))

Comment: @Script47 The reason behind me not posting the link (though it's been done, now, in the answer) was that, even with the >10K "view deleted posts" privilege, you can only do that **if you have a direct link**; at least, that's my understanding from other posts here on Meta.

Comment: It's not the first time TestDome [files a DMCA takedown request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376183/question-deleted-due-to-dmca-notice)

Comment: @10Rep At the time this question was published, I don't know that the OP had >10k rep, which is the threshold for seeing deleted questions. The fact that the OP now does have just under 20k is somewhat irrelevant to the question, so I'm not sure the edit is appropriate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Indeed - I've re-edited to make the historical lack of 10K points clear.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh, I was referring to the current rep level of the OP.

Comment: I though it was AM, not OP :) Or CP as Current Poster.. or QA as Question Author.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582152/what-are-special-values-that-need-to-be-taken-into-account-when-checking-for-the/58582300#58582300) you are referring to was deleted by Stack Exchange, not a community moderator. It was deleted because a DMCA request was received from TestDome.

This is noted in a comment on the question. I don't know if you can see those or not due to reputation level though, but here is a screenshot of said comment:

[image: DMCA Notice Comment By Employee]

Any such deletion will include a comment such as this one:

> Post removed due to a DMCA notice from <DMCA issuer>

Comment: interesting scenario. Though I'm reluctant, and too pessimistic here, to believe a quiz question is unique and original enough to merit or warrant copyrighting, it's good to know there is some attention to the notion.

Comment: I wonder if its sufficient to delete posts under DMCA and still have them available to view by users with sufficient rep. I can see it, so have you therefore not really deleted the copyrightable material.

Comment: It probably is @gbjbaanb as I doubt someone doing the quiz is likely to have sufficient reputation to view the post, and it also won't show up on search engines once they scan the site again (which is likely the key thing).