# Why were those question with up-voted answers deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Why were the below question deleted?

I don't know how to provide links to the questions, but you can find them by navigating to my profile, if you have >10k rep.

[image]

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097728/how-to-make-currency-converter-in-java)

[image]

[image]

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086046/required-string-parameter-id-is-not-present)

[image]

Comment: 10k users can see deleted questions *when they have a link to it*. They don't see deleted questions in your profile. And they can't search for them.

Comment: @BDL my bad, is there any way I can view them so I could provide the links?

Comment: You can paste the links from your profile to this question. Only a Mod could see them from your profile. Right click and copy the link

Comment: @SurajRao I no longer see them as links in my profile.

Comment: @BDL No, I had answers on those questions.

Comment: two more deleted after [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376163/why-was-this-question-with-upvoted-answers-deleted)? You have some bizzare luck

Comment: Yes, this time I'm quite sure no DMCA stuff though.

Comment: The first seems to be a poor question. You should avoid answering those

Comment: Found both links in the data explorer. Both seem to be of low quality, one is a duplicate.

Comment: @SurajRao I see your point regarding the currency converter one. I don't see how the `id` one is in any way worse than 95% of the content on its respective tags.

Comment: Funny that the second question even got upvotes.

Comment: The first question is simply too broad, and has no place on the site. In the second case, simply put, don't answer duplicate questions. Seeing you have <3k rep flag them as duplicate and they get put into the Close Vote Queue.

Comment: @Alex, do you really believe the second question provides any value over the duplicate target, and that we are missing anything for it having been deleted?

Comment: @yivi Frankly, no. That question provides no value, regardless of weather it is a duplicate or not. But I also think that 95% of the questions asked every day do not add any value whatsoever either. What I find peculiar is that *this* particular question was deleted, in spite of a positive vote count, with 2/3 votes from users who don't look like they have any expertise on the topic.

Comment: So you agree that the question is better deleted, but are making the case that it shouldn't because many other bad questions aren't?

Comment: Weather I think the question is or is not better off deleted is irrelevant, since I am not a moderator. For the sake of the argument, I think it is better off deleted, along with 95% of the content of this site. My case is not that "it shouldn't because many other bad questions aren't", since that is irrelevant as well.

Comment: Alex, the question was not deleted by "a moderator", but by the community. So being or not being a moderator is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Frankly, I am at a loss to understand what's your point. You agree that this question is better off deleted, you think other content should be deleted as well (no complaints from me there)... so I guess this is a happy outcome for everyone.

Comment: @Alex and... you **are** a moderator. You're not an elected, diamond mod. But you can (and likely do) moderate the site.

Comment: I have an issue with the deletion process though, since two of the delete votes came from users who don't seem to posses the competences to determine weather that is a duplicate or not and the question itself having a score of +3.

Comment: Alex, the question was **already closed as a duplicate** when deleted. As such, it is extremely easy to check the question and the target to determine how useful it is, even if you are not an subject matter expert. Also, you shouldn't be so sure about the competence of other users using their tag scores only. Most of us have more interests and experience than what's reflected by our SO score. I'm pretty sure that's the case for you as well.

Comment: And I do not understand how can you have an issue with the deletion process, when clearly you agree that the process worked as it should in this case. You've already said more than once that you also thought that nothing of value was lost with that question.

Comment: Potential duplicate, based on comments: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358487/should-users-unfamiliar-with-a-topic-wait-before-voting-to-close

Comment: @yivi I have an issue with the deletion process since it is vulnerable to me knowing two other high rep users and faking the consensus. Of course, I have no proof that happen, I can only point out the consensus looks odd.

Comment: The consensus looks anything but odd. Looks quite reasonable. It was a bad question that was better off deleted, and got deleted. It seems like clear evidence of **the system working as it should**, at least in this specific case. And if you want to make a case about the system being abused, you should look for cases to support that claim. This question? Not great support for that hypothesis.

Comment: You keep on focusing on the question, I am challenging the voters part. At the end of the day most of the crap on this site does not get deleted, in spite of being crap (which proves *the system does not work as it should*).

Comment: Well, then get to 10K, and start voting to delete.  I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve here; you're simultaneously complaining about having questions you answered deleted, because rigged voting, and complaining about low quality content not being deleted at all.  That's a very odd stance to reconcile.

Comment: I'm focusing on the question, because you asked about these questions' deletion. That one of these questions was upvoted is absolutely irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: I think that you are letting your attachment to those rep points cloud your better judgement. There is no issue here. Bad/not useful content can be deleted. Not all bad questions are deleted, because we are only human.

Comment: @yivi I think you are right, the gamification part of this site got the best out of me. I'm out, good luck!

Answer (score 12):

Having upvoted answers does not automatically make a question immune against deletion.  A typical scenario for deletion is a question which quickly attracts answers with upvotes, and then gets closed as a duplicate.  If neither the question nor the answers contribute anything above the question it was marked as a duplicate of, users are likely to vote to delete as noise / unnecessary pollution.

(I have not examined the questions in much detail; I am not familiar enough with the topics to have a strong opinion on whether in fact deleting was an appropriate action in these cases. My answer simply attempts to refute one of your apparent assumptions.)

Comment: Fair point, but I think "users are likely to vote to delete as noise / unnecessary pollution" holds true for smaller tags. How could this be true considering the content quality of the `java` tag, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How does the content quality of the [tag:java] tag affect this? If anything, I would think that it's more likely to attract upvotes on low-value content from beginners; it's not clear to me if you expect the opposite, and if so, why.

Comment: Exactly, the "high number of upvotes on low-value content from beginners" + "the high inflow of content of the Java tag" => unlikely to delete as noise / unnecessary pollution.

Comment: 1) Since you can't really use vote count to filter through the mess

Comment: So you are saying you agree but we should be doing this more?

Comment: 2) Most of the content should be deleted

Comment: Yes, why  shouldn't ***all*** content on the same level of quality deleted?

Comment: That's a nice ideal, but unfortunately, the reputation system is currently strongly in favor of the rep hunters over the quality assurance users. Please be invited to help in accomplishing this, and recruiting more users to do QA.

Comment: Also, two of the users who votes to delete have no real expertise in `Java`, much less in `Spring`, which I find peculiar, to say at least. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi?tab=badges https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts?tab=badges&sort=class&page=1

Comment: @AlexRolea Not having expertise in certain tag doesn't means user cannot identify duplicate. As for your "concern", 1. You shouldn't answer bad questions 2. You shouldn't answer potential duplicate questions without adding more value to the existing answers 3. duplicate questions without addition values will be closed 4. close vote queue has been backlogged for at least a few years, so yes, we are not closing enough questions

Comment: If you believe that your answer do add addition value, then you can always add a new answer to the dup target question. Otherwise, I don't think there's any more point to argue about. Other questions deserving closure but wasn't doesn't make the question you answered undeserving.

Comment: @tweray Well, you seem to have a .net background. If you have the time, lets do an experiment. Are you able to determine *why* that question is a duplicate?

Comment: @AlexRolea Your discussion is becoming fairly tangential to this answer. Comments are meant for requesting clarifiations etc, not for extended arguments. Maybe try to move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @AlexRolea You want the question undeleted and reopened, so the onus is on you to explain why the question is useful, and not a duplicate.  Given that you have provided no such reason over this entire thread, I think it's pretty safe to say even *you* think it's a duplicate.  In fact, you've stated that you think the question is a duplicate and doesn't provide any value.  There is no need for any additional people to state why they don't think it's useful or that it's a duplicate; consensus has already been reached, and there is no reasons given for why the action should be reversed.